# I cant login on Server - Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know why I can't login on the server, I can access on server local but hen I try login on the server that is impossible. I'm using Laravel 6.2 and Auth process by Default

I run this command
`php artisan ui vue --auth`

This is my login ctrl

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

And this is my User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
    * The attributes that are mass assignable.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
    * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
    * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    protected $appends = ['client'];

    public function countriesAccess(){

        $countries = Countries::whereIn('id',explode(',',$this->countriesId))->get();
        return $countries;
    }

    public function getClientAttribute()
    {
        $client = Clients::where('id',$this->clientId)->first();
        return $this->client = $client->name;
    }

    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new MyResetPassword($token));
    }
    public function country(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Countries','countryId');
    }

}
```

In config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
]
```

I run

`PHP artisan optimize`

And nothing works. Please help me.
Ahh the server ins a vHost in AWS

Comment: Did you create an account? Meaning does the remote server's database have the data in it for the user you're trying to log in as?

Comment: Yeah, of course, I tested connecting with the database from the local server and all is right

Comment: Fixed my problem was APP_ENV=local to APP_ENV=production